# Remove break/label from continuous axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Probably a simple solution, but I can't figure out why the following happens.

```
var1 <- runif(4, 1, 5)
var2 <- runif(4, 1, 5)
var3 <- runif(4, 1, 5)
time <- c(0,1,3,4)
time2 <- as.factor(c(0,1,3,4))
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, time)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var2, colour = "var2")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var3, colour = "var3"))
```

This gives:

[image]

The point however is that the times I have are: 0, 1, 3 and 4. Not 2. Because `time` is numeric (or integer), it also puts '2' on the x-axis. For this reason, I made time as factor (or character) and tried plotting it using the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(time2)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var2, colour = "var2")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var3, colour = "var3"))
```

So the only difference is that `time2` is a factor here. The result is an empty plot, accompanied by the following message:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to 
adjust the group aesthetic?
```

How can I get a plot like the one I showed, but with `time == 0, 1, 3, 4` on the X-axis, instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify your values, simply remove "2" from x-axis. To do this use function `scale_x_continuous`.

Data:

```
var1 <- runif(4, 1, 5)
var2 <- runif(4, 1, 5)
var3 <- runif(4, 1, 5)
time <- c(0,1,3,4)
time2 <- as.factor(c(0,1,3,4))
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, time)

# Transform data from wide to long 
# This will simplify plotting (3 lines of code to 1 line)
library(reshape2)
dfMelt <- melt(df, "time")
```

Plot:

```
# Using scale_x_continuous we specify breaks (ie, use only existing values)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfMelt, aes(time, value, color = variable)) + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(dfMelt$time))
```

Result:
[image]

**However**, this is time data (ie, it's continuous and 3 can't go after 1). So in practice people use points and lines:

```
ggplot(dfMelt, aes(time, value, color = variable)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_line()
```

To produce plots like this:

[image]

And from this plot we can see that data is continuous, but we have measurements only at points (0,1,3,4).